# debug test case in java

Tags: java, junit

Why the debug point not moving to if else clause below, there was no error in `testServ` method and working as expected.

```
@Test
public void testXMAS() {
    StringBuffer fb = xmsObj.testServ("XZXZXXX", 25, "", "", "");

    if (fb != null)
       logger.debug("ABCD done , issues: " + fb.toString());
    else
       logger.debug("ABCD not done , successfull:");
    }
}
```

after  executing below loop is not going to `return sb` statement in the testServ() method? That is why debug point in @Test class is not triggering.

```
                    while (br.readLine() != null) {
                String returnString = br.readLine();
                if (rString.contains("eee")) {
                    log.debug(" Mie:" + rString);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which logger message is displayed?

Comment: What do you mean it's not moving to the if-else clause? Do you have a break point at each logger statment? Is it printing one of the log statements?

Comment: no , I put debug, but is not going to if or else block. No logger message printed, only the log.debug() placed in side method are printed as expected

Comment: Does the testServ method ever return, then?

Comment: Your "while" loop is wrong; you're calling `readLine()` twice when you should be calling it once; that's a recipe for a NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Your stringbuffer is called `fb`, you are checking if `sb` is null

Comment: sorry I corrected that but not pasted code here correctly  but that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

if neither the if nor else clause is executing, then either testServ isn't terminating, or it's throwing an unchecked exception which you are propagating up...

Comment: I added the block code to my post where it was stopped propagating inside testServ

Comment: if i add "break in the while , it is working. But wondering why?

Comment: well, the bufferedReader javadoc says readline returns null only when the end of the stream is reached: where is this data coming from? Are you sure the stream reaches the end? (e.g. a fileinputstream will eventually reach the end of the file, but if the data is coming from, say, a network socket, then the loop won't terminate until the socket is closed...

Comment: PLEASE, if you want help, please cut and paste and post the exact contents of your testSrv method; if that is too long, then copy your application to a test area, and whittle it down, removing unnecessary code, until you have something that compiles, runs, and demonstrates the problem. You are not helping yourself by manually copying only a portion of the code. E.g. you show code for a loop that uses returnString and rString -- are these supposed to be the same variable? Where is the 'return sb' call? For that matter - what is 'sb', since it doesn't appear in your code? What return statement?